# Setting query time-limit for certain user roles in SSMS 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

I want to set the query execution time for certain users in SSMS. I tried setting the Query Governor to prevent-long running queries under Object Explorer -> Properties for server -> Connection. But this gave sets the value for the entire Server and not just for certain users. I also tried to set the remote query execution time, but as my users are querying directly in SSMS it did not seem to affect them. Can someone give me some help on how to limit query execution time allowed for certain users bur not for everyone?